# C++ git repo compile trouble

Tags: c++, makefile, compiler-errors

I've just downloaded this repo: [UCTDom](https://github.com/RobinTo/UCTDom)

And opening the project in Clion from the /UCTDom-master dir, or attempting to make from /UCTDom-master/Console4SimpleStorage/Console4SimpleStorage results in this missing architecture error:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "BigMoneyAI::~BigMoneyAI()", referenced from:
      Player::~Player() in main-cd1c38.o
  "FlatUCBMod::~FlatUCBMod()", referenced from:
      Player::~Player() in main-cd1c38.o
  "HumanInputAI::~HumanInputAI()", referenced from:
      Player::~Player() in main-cd1c38.o
  "DoubleWitchAI::~DoubleWitchAI()", referenced from:
      Player::~Player() in main-cd1c38.o
  "SingleWitchAI::~SingleWitchAI()", referenced from:
      Player::~Player() in main-cd1c38.o
  "UCTMonteCarlo::~UCTMonteCarlo()", referenced from:
      Player::~Player() in main-cd1c38.o
  "Game::initialize()", referenced from:
      playGame(Game&) in main-cd1c38.o
  "Game::writeCSVLog(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >)", referenced from:
      _main in main-cd1c38.o
  "Game::writeToFile(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >)", referenced from:
      writeToFile(Game&, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >) in main-cd1c38.o
  "Game::writeMoveHistoryToFile(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >)", referenced from:
      _main in main-cd1c38.o
  "Game::play()", referenced from:
      playGame(Game&) in main-cd1c38.o
  "Game::Game()", referenced from:
      _main in main-cd1c38.o
  "FlatUCB::~FlatUCB()", referenced from:
      Player::~Player() in main-cd1c38.o
  "RandomAI::~RandomAI()", referenced from:
      Player::~Player() in main-cd1c38.o
  "GameState::~GameState()", referenced from:
      Game::~Game() in main-cd1c38.o
  "std::__1::locale::use_facet(std::__1::locale::id&) const", referenced from:
      std::__1::ctype<char> const& std::__1::use_facet<std::__1::ctype<char> >(std::__1::locale const&) in main-cd1c38.o
  "std::__1::ios_base::getloc() const", referenced from:
      std::__1::basic_ios<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >::widen(char) const in main-cd1c38.o
  "std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >::__init(char const*, unsigned long, unsigned long)", referenced from:
      std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > std::__1::operator+<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&, char const*) in main-cd1c38.o
  "std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >::__init(unsigned long, char)", referenced from:
      std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >::basic_string(unsigned long, char) in main-cd1c38.o
  "std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >::append(char const*, unsigned long)", referenced from:
      std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > std::__1::operator+<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&, char const*) in main-cd1c38.o
  "std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >::basic_string(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&)", referenced from:
      writeToFile(Game&, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >) in main-cd1c38.o
      _main in main-cd1c38.o
  "std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >::~basic_string()", referenced from:
      writeToFile(Game&, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >) in main-cd1c38.o
      _main in main-cd1c38.o
      std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > std::__1::operator+<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&, char const*) in main-cd1c38.o
      Game::~Game() in main-cd1c38.o
      Move::~Move() in main-cd1c38.o
      std::__1::ostreambuf_iterator<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> > std::__1::__pad_and_output<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >(std::__1::ostreambuf_iterator<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >, char const*, char const*, char const*, std::__1::ios_base&, char) in main-cd1c38.o
  "std::__1::basic_istream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >::operator>>(int&)", referenced from:
      _main in main-cd1c38.o
  "std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >::put(char)", referenced from:
      std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >& std::__1::endl<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&) in main-cd1c38.o
  "std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >::flush()", referenced from:
      std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >& std::__1::endl<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&) in main-cd1c38.o
  "std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >::sentry::sentry(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&)", referenced from:
      std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >& std::__1::__put_character_sequence<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&, char const*, unsigned long) in main-cd1c38.o
  "std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >::sentry::~sentry()", referenced from:
      std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >& std::__1::__put_character_sequence<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&, char const*, unsigned long) in main-cd1c38.o
  "std::__1::cin", referenced from:
      _main in main-cd1c38.o
  "std::__1::cout", referenced from:
      playGame(Game&) in main-cd1c38.o
      _main in main-cd1c38.o
  "std::__1::ctype<char>::id", referenced from:
      std::__1::ctype<char> const& std::__1::use_facet<std::__1::ctype<char> >(std::__1::locale const&) in main-cd1c38.o
  "std::__1::locale::~locale()", referenced from:
      std::__1::basic_ios<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >::widen(char) const in main-cd1c38.o
  "std::__1::ios_base::__set_badbit_and_consider_rethrow()", referenced from:
      std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >& std::__1::__put_character_sequence<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&, char const*, unsigned long) in main-cd1c38.o
  "std::__1::ios_base::clear(unsigned int)", referenced from:
      std::__1::ios_base::setstate(unsigned int) in main-cd1c38.o
  "std::__1::to_string(int)", referenced from:
      _main in main-cd1c38.o
  "std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > std::__1::operator+<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >(char const*, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&)", referenced from:
      _main in main-cd1c38.o
  "std::terminate()", referenced from:
      ___clang_call_terminate in main-cd1c38.o
  "operator delete(void*)", referenced from:
      _main in main-cd1c38.o
      std::__1::_DeallocateCaller::__do_call(void*) in main-cd1c38.o
  "operator new(unsigned long)", referenced from:
      _main in main-cd1c38.o
  "___cxa_begin_catch", referenced from:
      ___clang_call_terminate in main-cd1c38.o
      std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >& std::__1::__put_character_sequence<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&, char const*, unsigned long) in main-cd1c38.o
  "___cxa_call_unexpected", referenced from:
      std::__1::__vector_base<Move, std::__1::allocator<Move> >::__destruct_at_end(Move*) in main-cd1c38.o
      std::__1::allocator<Move>::deallocate(Move*, unsigned long) in main-cd1c38.o
      std::__1::__vector_base<LogItem, std::__1::allocator<LogItem> >::__destruct_at_end(LogItem*) in main-cd1c38.o
      std::__1::allocator<LogItem>::deallocate(LogItem*, unsigned long) in main-cd1c38.o
      std::__1::ostreambuf_iterator<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >::ostreambuf_iterator(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&) in main-cd1c38.o
  "___cxa_end_catch", referenced from:
      std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >& std::__1::__put_character_sequence<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&, char const*, unsigned long) in main-cd1c38.o
  "___gxx_personality_v0", referenced from:
      writeToFile(Game&, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >) in main-cd1c38.o
      _main in main-cd1c38.o
      std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > std::__1::operator+<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&, char const*) in main-cd1c38.o
      Game::~Game() in main-cd1c38.o
      std::__1::__vector_base<Move, std::__1::allocator<Move> >::__destruct_at_end(Move*) in main-cd1c38.o
      std::__1::allocator<Move>::deallocate(Move*, unsigned long) in main-cd1c38.o
      std::__1::__vector_base<LogItem, std::__1::allocator<LogItem> >::__destruct_at_end(LogItem*) in main-cd1c38.o
      ...
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [main.o] Error 1

Process finished with exit code 2
```

I have figured out that perhaps the undefined deconstructors is an aspect of this, but it seems to me that this would have been a problem to the creators of the repo so I also figure that there is some simple file trick I have to do for the makefile in order to have it compile

for quick reference, heres the makefile:

```
CXX=g++
CXXFLAGS= -std=c++0x -Wall -pedantic
LDFLAGS=
SOURCES=main.cpp BigMoneyAI.cpp CardManager.cpp Game.cpp GameState.cpp HumanInputAI.cpp Move.cpp Node.cpp Player.cpp PlayerState.cpp UCTMonteCarlo.cpp
OBJECTS=$(SOURCES:.cpp=.o)
EXECUTABLE=dominionuct

all: $(SOURCES) $(EXECUTABLE)
    
$(EXECUTABLE): $(OBJECTS) 
    $(CC) $(LDFLAGS) $(OBJECTS) -o $@

.cpp.o:
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $< -o $@
```

I'm at a bit of a loss where to go with this, any help or tips to investigate would be much appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: Well, one problem is you're using a C compiler (the `CC` and `CFLAGS`) variables to try to compile your C++ code.

Comment: Ah, so they should be switched to what? Not really proficient in C++

Comment: Well, you defined some variables `CXX` to hold the compiler and `CXXFLAGS` to hold the flags, right there in your makefile, so I assume you want to use those.

Comment: Not all required files are listed in SOURCES.

Comment: oh CXX solved some of the issues, still complaining about decompilers, which would probably be fixed by creating some decompilers. Added some stuff to the sources as well, still figuring out whats required.

Comment: FTR not my repo, just trying to get it to run ;-;

Comment: I have no idea what the use would be for a decompiler.  That's almost an unheard of tool in C++ in particular.  Are you sure that's what the error is saying?  Anyway, sounds like you got through this issue.  You should open a new question with new details about any new problems you have.  Cheers!

Comment: Oh I meant deconstructor* whoops

Thanks for the help!